# Attaching an entity of type '' failed because another entity has the same primary key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I have one little problem with my WebApi application.
This problem occurs when i add new entity into my database.

Entities:

```
public sealed class Lot : Entity
{
    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool InCredit { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(1), Range(1, 10)]
    public int PhaseNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal DesiredPrice { get; set; }

    public Guid? AcceptedBetId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpirationDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public Car Car { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Bet> Bets { get; set; }

    public Lot()
    {
        Bets = new List<Bet>();
    }
}

public sealed class Bet : Entity
{
    [Required, Range(0.0, double.MaxValue)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue)]
    public int BetNumber { get; set; }

    public Lot Lot { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Code where i want to add new Bet entity into my database:

```
Lot lot;
using (LotsManager lotsManager = new LotsManager())
{
     lot = await lotsManager.GetLotAsync(model.LotId);
}

User user;
using (UserManager userManager = new UserManager())
{
      user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(model.UserInfoId);
}

var bet = new Bet
{
      Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      Price = model.Price,
      CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
      BetNumber = lastBetNumber + 1,
      Lot = lot,
      User = user
 };

 await _betsManager.SaveBetAsync(bet);
```

On this place a add my entity into DB (db: my SQL)

```
protected async Task Save<T>(T entity) where T : Entity
    {
        using (var dbContextTransaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var dbEntity = await _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == entity.Id);

                _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
                _context.Entry(entity).State = dbEntity != null ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                dbContextTransaction?.Commit();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                dbContextTransaction?.Rollback();

                var error = ex.EntityValidationErrors.First().ValidationErrors.First();
                throw new InvalidModelException(error.ErrorMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dbContextTransaction?.Rollback();

                throw new InvalidDbOperationException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i call my save method, my code throw this exception:

> Attaching an entity of type 'WebCar.Domain.Entities.Lot' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I am try to use

```
_context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
or
_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

But the code still throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that is causing the problem:

```
  var dbEntity = await _context.Set<T>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
  _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
```

In this scenario, if you find an existing entity, it just got stored in the context.  If you try to add one that already exists, EF can't handle that.  There are a couple of ways you can get around this.  I'll show two:

```
 var dbEntity = await _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
```

In theory, if you don't track it, then you should be able to add the other one.

However, I think this way is better:

```
bool doesEntityExist = await _context.Set<T>().Any(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
_context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
_context.Entry(entity).State = doesEntityExist ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
```

Comment: `var dbEntity = await _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
 _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
context.Entry(entity).State = dbEntity != null ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;`

Thx, but problem still not lost :(

Comment: Hmm, try removing the .Attach call.  Just use Entry(entity).State instead, then.  Or try the 2nd style.